# How to make music list in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I choose the music file using `JFileChoose` and I want to add what I choose on frame (in `JTextArea`)
In that case, I want to list name and time of what I choose.
How to list all of them? 
And is that right about what I do something (JTextarea,JFileChoose)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question: what precisely are you trying to display? The file name and file properties? Something else? Can you show an image of what you mean? If you're just displaying data, look into possibly using a JList or JTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just implement custome file filtering based on extensions to obtain music file names in a specific directory.

```
class CustomeFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        boolean valid = false;
        //if (fileName.startsWith("j") ) 
        if ( fileName.endsWith(".mp3") || fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {

            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

}
```

The implementation

```
      File file = new File("C:\\My Music");
      File[] contens = file.listFiles(new CustomeFilter());
        for (File contens : conten) {
            System.out.println(conten);
        }
```

Then just put the list on any swing components you want.

---

But if you get the file from the *JFileChooser* instead, then

```
public File getCurrentFileInformation() {
        // display file dialog
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        // if  Cancel button on dialog clicked, return
        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
            System.exit(1);

        File selectedFileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); // get selected file


        if ((selectedFileName == null) || (selectedFileName.getName().equals(""))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File Name",
                    "Invalid File Name", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        } // end if

        return selectedFileName;
    }
```

So you get the selected file information with :

`File fileInfo = getCurrentFileInformation();` like *`fileInfo.lastModified()`* or *`fileInfo.length()`*